# Material-UI: Button in CardActionArea

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `CardActionArea` when I click on it redirects me to another page:

```
<Card>
    <CardContent>
        <CardActionArea component={RouterLink} to={`/poll/${poll.id}`} >
            // My code
        </CardActionArea>
    </CardContent>
</Card>
```

I put a `Button` in the `CardActionArea`, when the `Button` is clicked it does an other action:

```
<Card>
    <CardContent>
        <CardActionArea component={RouterLink} to={`/poll/${poll.id}`} >
            <Button  onClick={props.myAction}>
                {answer.text}
            </Button>
        </CardActionArea>
    </CardContent>
</Card>
```

**My problem is:**

When I click on the `Button`, I also click on the `CardActionArea`.
I don't want to click on the `CardActionArea`, but just on the `Button` and call my `myAction()` without  being redirected.

Someone help me ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to call `event.stopPropagation()` in the Button's `onClick` and `onMouseDown` events in order to prevent those events from propagating to the `CardActionArea`. Stopping propagation of the click event is the most important aspect, but stopping propagation of the mouse-down event prevents the ripple effect from occurring on the `CardActionArea` (so the ripple only occurs on the Button).

Also if the `CardActionArea` component is overridden in such a manner as to make it an `a` tag, you may also need to call `event.preventDefault()` in the Button's click event to prevent the default browser behavior of navigating to the `href` specified by the `a` tag.

Here's a working example (based on one of the [demos](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#media)):

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    height: 140
  }
});

export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea
        component="a"
        href="https://material-ui.com"
        onClick={() => console.log("CardActionArea clicked")}
      >
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="https://material-ui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
          <Button
            size="small"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onMouseDown={event => event.stopPropagation()}
            onClick={event => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log("Button clicked");
            }}
          >
            Learn More
          </Button>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Button in CardActionArea]

Comment: It works, but I get an error in console stating that `<button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>`

Comment: @Stormwaker In the example, the `component` of `CardActionArea` has been overridden to be `<a href...>` instead of `<button>`, and therefore it does not get that console error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the ripple effect works in mobile view.
So I also set `onTouchStart`.

```
<Button

  // Stop Ripple Effect
  onTouchStart={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
  onMouseDown={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}

  onClick={(event) => {
    // Prevent CardActionArea Click
    event.preventDefault()

    handleClick()
  }
>
  Learn More
</Button>
```

Comment: Indeed, good answer.