# Link within a Disabled CardActionArea

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

#1  I have a `CardActionArea` that, when clicked, navigates me to another page.
#2  I have a `Link` inside the `CardActionArea` that pulls up a website.

There are several `Cards` using this `CardActionArea`, and some of these are disabled.

**My Problem Is:**
I want the link inside the `CardActionArea` to still be clickable even when the `CardActionArea` itself is disabled. (or in other words, when the `CardActionArea` is disabled, I want to disable #1 but not #2)

I've utilized the help in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590919/material-ui-button-in-cardactionarea](https://stackoverflow.com) to allow the `link` to be clicked without triggering the on-click effect of the `CardActionArea`. However, this doesn't allow the `link` to be clickable on a disabled `card`.

Comment: Make the `CardActionArea` positioned relative, and make the `Link` absolute, while increasint its `z-index`. Or, just position the `Link` relative and increase the `z-index`.